# Criteria API read data in chunks with NOT IN statement

Tags: java, sql, db2, eclipselink, criteria-api

I am using `EclipseLink 2.6.4`, `Java 8` and `DB2` for database. I have to write query to read data with `NOT IN` statement providing a large set of values for `NOT IN` statement.

Basically I have set of external IDs with over 10000 values:

```
Set<Integer> externalIDs = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("ExternalID1", "ExternalID2", "ExternalID3",....)); //externalIDs.size() == 10k+
```

Note: I know that the limit for `NOT IN` statement with DB2 is 1000 values, so I am creating partioned `NOT IN` statements in the query, and it looks like this:

```
public List<UserEntity> findNotReferencedToRemove2(Set<String> externalIds) {

  CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<UserEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(UserEntity.class);
  Root<UserEntity> root = cq.from(UserEntity.class);

  Path<String> externalId1 = root.get(UserEntity_.relation1).get(RelationEntity1_.externalId);
  Path<String> externalId2 = root.get(UserEntity_.relation2).get(RelationEntity2_.externalId);
  Path<String> externalId3 = root.get(UserEntity_.relation3).get(RelationEntity3_.externalId);
  Path<String> externalId4 = root.get(UserEntity_.relation4).get(RelationEntity4_.externalId);
  Path<String> externalId5 = root.get(UserEntity_.relation5).get(RelationEntity5_.externalId);

  Predicate predicate = cb.and(
      partitionedNotIn(cb, externalId1, externalIds),
      partitionedNotIn(cb, externalId2, externalIds),
      partitionedNotIn(cb, externalId3, externalIds),
      partitionedNotIn(cb, externalId4, externalIds),
      partitionedNotIn(cb, externalId5, externalIds)
  );

  return entityManager.createQuery(cq.where(predicate)).getResultList();
}

//creates NOT IN statement splited in chunks of 999 values connected with AND 
private<C> Predicate partitionedNotIn(CriteriaBuilder cb, Path<C> path, Collection<C> ids) {
    if (ids.isEmpty()) {
      return cb.and();
    }
    return cb.and(partition(ids).stream().map(path::in).map(cb::not).toArray(Predicate[]::new));
  }

  private <C> Collection<List<C>> partition(Collection<C> list) {
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / 999))
        .values();
  }
```

Private method `partionedNotIn()` just splits `NOT IN` statements in chunks of 999 values to not reach maximum of 1000 values.

But as you can see I have 5 `NOT IN` statements and for each 10000 values provided and in total is 50000 and I am hitting limit in DB of hosted variable length.

Anyway, the goal is to split this in chunks so I don't have 50k+ values in total for `NOT IN` statements and currently don't have any idea how to achieve this. With just `IN` statement it would be easy.

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Store the values in a temporary table and evaluate against it?!

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the values for the not in? Is it a file, then you might be able to use an external table. Or create a temporary table and insert the values into that table and use it in your query.